# Array.Initialize - Why does this method exist?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I stumbled upon a method today. I'm talking about: [Array.Initialize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.initialize(v=vs.110).aspx).

According to the documentation:

> This method is designed to help compilers support value-type arrays; most users do not need this method.

How does this method is responsible for making the compiler *support* value types? As far as I'm concerned this method just:

> Initializes every element of the value-type Array by calling the default constructor of the value type.

Also, why is it *public*? I don't see myself with the need of calling this method, compilers already initialize arrays when created, so manually calling this method will be redundant and useless.

Even when my intention would be resetting the values of an array, I would still not call it, I would create a new one. `array = new int[]`.

So, it seems that this method exist just for the sake of the compiler. Why is this? Can anyone give me some more details?

Comment: And if you wanted to reset the values without creating a new array you should probably use `Array.Clear()` instead, too.

Comment: Close vote? This seems a valid question to me. Maybe you just voted to close based on title? I know _Why does this method exist_ is some kind of tricky but if you read all question, I'm pretty sure you will agree with me.

Comment: @SonerGönül "Why was the framework designed this way" is a question on the people that designed it can answer.  Anyone else is just going to be guessing.  The question isn't appropriate for SO; if you want to know why Microsoft designed .NET this way, ask *them*.

Comment: Quite often there are reasons to "why was this design decision made", which are public knowledge, or common knowledge for experts on the subject. In particular, there may be a specific use case for some esoteric feature, which explains why it exists. Looking at the top answer, I think this question falls into that category, and is not opinion based.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's worth noting that the rules of .NET are different to the rules of C#.

There are things we can do in .NET that we can't do in C#, generally either because the code is not verifiable (`ref` return types for example) or because they could introduce some confusion.

In C# `struct`s cannot have a defined parameterless constructor, and calling `new SomeValueType()` works by creating a zero-filled portion of memory (all fields therefore being `0` for numeric types, `null` for reference types, and the result of this same rule again for other value-types).

In .NET you can have a parameterless constructor on a value type.

It's probably a bad idea to do so. For one thing the rules about just when it is called and just when the memory of the value is zero-filled, and what happens upon assignment in different cases aren't entirely simple (e.g. `new SomeValueType()` will call it but `new T()` in a generic method where `T` is `SomeValueType` will not!). Life is simpler if the result of `new SomeValueType()` will always be zero-filling. That no doubt influenced the design of C# not allowing this even though .NET does.

For this reason, Array.Initialize() will never make sense on new arrays of any type that was written in C#, because calling the constructor and zero-filling is the same thing.

But by the same token, it's possible for a type to be written in another .NET language (at the very least, you can do it in CIL) that does have a parameterless constructor that actually has an effect. And for that reason its possible that a compiler for such a language would want its equivalent to `new SomeValueType[3]` to call that constructor on all the types in the array. And therefore it's sensible to have a method in the framework that allows such a fill to be done, so that a compiler for such a language can make use of it.

> Also, why is it public?

So it can be called by code produced by such a hypothetical constructor even in a context where security restrictions prevent it from calling private methods of another assembly.

Comment: "You can now do this with C# 6": no, you can't. This feature has been considered, and IIRC it was even  implemented in one of the pre-release versions, but it has eventually been withdrawn. In the final version, you get this error: `CS0568 Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque ah,thanks, you can tell I haven't actually played with the latest version yet! Also, good! The vagueries of parameterless constructors on value types would likely not be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

For me myself it looks like the Initialize() method runs through the array and recreates the *Value Types* within. So with a *new array* you get a new empty array and so you get with *Array.Clear()*, but with *Array.Initialize()* you get an Array full of fresh created *Value Types* (types and length based on the old array).

And that should be all of the difference.

Comment: Suppose I have `int[] a = new int[3] { 7, 9, 13, };` in C#. Your answer _could_ be read as to mean that if I do `a.Initialize();` on that, then I will have an array of zeros (the `default(int)`) after that. This is wrong, however. If you want that feature, use `Array.Clear(a, 0, a.Length);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [CLR source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/classlibnative/bcltype/arraynative.cpp#L226), the method traverses each index of the array and initializes the value type on that index by calling the default constructor, similar to `initobj` IL instruction (I wonder what happens when the constructor throws an exception, though). The method is public because calling a private method directly from IL would make it a bit unverifiable.

Today's C# compilers do not initialize each element of the array when creating it, simply "set" each index to the default value of the type. C# 6 introduces implementing default constructors for value types (which were already supported by CLR), so this is needed for languages with different array creation semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the expected use in the test code:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/3015ff7afb4936a1c5c5856daa4e3482e6b390a9/tests/src/CoreMangLib/cti/system/array/arrayinitialize.cs

Basically, it sets an array of non-intrinsic value-types back to their default(T) state.

It does not seem like an amazingly useful tool, but I can see how it could be useful for zero'ing out arrays of non-intrinsic value data.